# Problems with sfml function in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, sfml

I have a sfml c++ project. In this project, if I use the "sf::Mouse::setPosition" sfml method, the program crashes in 2-3 seconds after launch. If i don't use the "sf::Mouse::setPosition" sfml method, the runs successfully.

OS: Kubuntu 22.10 x64,
Kernel: 5.19.0-28-generic,
Video card: GT 730,
Compiler: gcc version 12.2.0 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1),
SFML has installed by apt, libsfml-dev version 2.5.1+dfsg-2.
Makefile:
`

```
compile:./main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp
        g++ main.o -o app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

run:
        ./app
```

`

I've tried to use legacy nvidia-driver-390, xserver-xorg-video-nouveau but it doesn't work. Maybe I should compile sfml source code for better compatibility, but i don't know how to do this. Also the problem might be in gcc version (maybe sfml 2.5.1 doesn't support 12.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little program using the sfml set mouse position function and the below works on even a cmd line linux with x11.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                sf::Mouse::setPosition({0,0});
        }


        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem is due to your compilation with g++. I compiled my program using the command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```